# How to update multiple rows with different values in a single execution in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

We know that in mysql instead of executing the below queries 3 times we can do the same in a single exection given in 1> and 2>

```
UPDATE feedbacks SET _id = '5c6a8bcfce1454086fefb879' WHERE user_rol = '26-02-2018';  
UPDATE feedbacks SET _id = '5c6a89d3ce1454086fefb877' WHERE user_rol = '26-02-2017'; 
UPDATE feedbacks SET _id = '5c6a896ece1454086fefb876' WHERE user_rol = '26-02-2016';
```

1>

```
INSERT INTO feedbacks (_id, added_on) 
VALUES 
    ('5c6a8bcfce1454086fefb879', '26-02-2018'),
    ('5c6a89d3ce1454086fefb877', '26-02-2017'),
    ('5c6a896ece1454086fefb876', '26-02-2016')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE added_on = VALUES(added_on)
```

2>

```
UPDATE feedbacks
    SET added_on = CASE 
        WHEN _id = '5c6a8bcfce1454086fefb879' THEN '26-02-2018'
        WHEN _id = '5c6a89d3ce1454086fefb877' THEN '26-02-2017'
        WHEN _id = '5c6a896ece1454086fefb876' THEN '26-02-2016'
    END
WHERE _id IN ('5c6a8bcfce1454086fefb879', '5c6a89d3ce1454086fefb877', '5c6a896ece1454086fefb876')
```

Now my question is can we have any way to do the same (updating multiple rows with different values in a single execution) in mongodb?

Answer (score -1):

In mongo with same condition or query, you can update multiple records by setting the 'multi' flag as true. Please refer link.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

But, conditions are different this will not work.

For Bulk Update, You can refer:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/#Bulk.find.update